# convert trim logic into function has unexpected result

Tags: php, arrays

Here's some test data in an associative array for which I'm trying to build a trim function:

```
$header = [
        'comment1' => '   abc   ',
        'comment2' => 'abc   ',
        'comment3' => '   abc',
        'comment4' => 'abc'
];
```

The `foreach` line code below works correctly to trim the values within the array and keep the original keys:

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($header, 1) . '</pre>';
var_dump($header);
foreach ($header as &$val) $val = trim($val);   // <--- this is the line that does the trimming
echo '<pre>' . print_r($header, 1) . '</pre>';
var_dump($header);
```

Outputs:
[image]

However, when I attempt to make the `foreach` into a function like so

```
function trimValues($array) {
    foreach ($array as &$value) {
        $value = trim($value);
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($header, 1) . '</pre>';
var_dump($header);
trimValues($header);  // <--- this is the line that calls the trimming function
echo '<pre>' . print_r($header, 1) . '</pre>';
var_dump($header);
```

The output shows the trim didn't work
[image]

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Literally the first line in the accepted answer is your issue : *By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get changed outside of the function). To allow a function to modify its arguments, they must be passed by reference.*

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I see the small detail that was overlooked.  The `&` was missing in the first line of the function -
`function trimValues(&$array) {` ...